# Background Image Not Appearing On Span CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a simple span on my page with a class `eah-logo-img`, and inside of my CSS, I have tried to set the background image for it. However, It is not working for some reason.

This is my HTML:

```
<span class="eah-logo-img"></span>
```

and this is my CSS:

```
.eah-logo-img{
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background: url('img/logo_def_white.gif');
    background-size: auto;
}
```

My image is inside of the `img` folder (inside the same folder as the CSS; so it should be working.).
I have made sure the name is right, and I have checked Chrome inspect element and made sure the link is correct.

I am unsure why this isn't working.

Cheers.

Comment: Span is an inline element. Add `display: inline-block` to your css

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `span` element has no actual width or height – and therefor you do see little of any background, because it is displayed in an area that is 0*0 pixels big.

`width` and `height` *by definition* have no effect on inline elements (which span is by default.)

So add `display:inline-block` or `display:block` to your span, or float it, or position it absolutely – so that width and height are *allowed* to have an effect.

Comment: done this. it shows. however, it is not the specified size. even though I have specified my width and height.

Comment: nvm, fixed it! :) ty

Answer (score 1):

In your css add

> display:block

or

> display:inline-block

better yet do not use span if you want to define the width and height, use div instead.